# How to find the number of automorphisms on $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Well, I was trying find out the number of group homomorphisms from $U(20)$ onto $U(15)$ which I reduce to the problem of finding the number of automorphisms for $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_4$. But don't know how shall I proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/662491/28900).

Comment: But you just asked this question a few hours ago. What do you think you're doing? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436088/how-many-onto-group-homomorhisms-are-there-from-mathbb-z-2-times-mathbb-z-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's represent $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ by pairs $(a,b)$. Note that $(1,0),(1,2),(0,2)$ are the only elements of order $2$, and furthermore $(0,2)$ is the only one which can be halved (that is, $2x=(0,2)$ for some $x$). This means that every automorphism fixes $(0,2)$, and sends $(1,0)$ to either $(1,0)$ or $(1,2)$. Furthermore, it must send $(0,1)$ (a half of $(0,2)$) to one of $(0,1),(1,1),(0,3),(1,3)$; and this choice determines the rest of the automorphism (since $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ together form a generating set).

Explicitly, suppose that $(1,0)$ gets sent to $(1,2a)$ and that $(0,1)$ gets sent to $(b,2c+1)$, where $a,b,c \in \{0,1\}$. Then $(x,y)$ gets sent to $(x+by,2ax+2cy+y)$. In total, we get $8$ automorphisms.

Comment: This is not correct. To start, (1,0) and (0,2) are not the only elements of order 2. You also have (1,2), so the automorphism could send (1,0) to (1,2). And there are four choices for the "halves" of (0,2), since you can also take (1,1) or (1,3). The number of automorphisms is 8.